# How can I make a menu on Actionbar?

Tags: android, select, menu, android-actionbar

How can I make a menuitem on ActionBar where I can select a number between 1 and 10?

Please write me some code, I am a beginner Android programmer.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

MenuItem is not meant to be used like this. Please look at [this](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html), I think what you're looking for is View Control, but this isn't even sure. What do you want to do with these numbers ? Keep in mind that the MenuItem is used to display some actions.